# My array values are incorrect when loading them into a dialogue box Visual Basic 2010

Tags: vb.net, linq, random, numbers

I wasn't sure what I should name the topic, but I'll explain the situation.

I have an array with stored card values. Right now I'm implementing dodge and block cards to my game, so I decided to make a new dialogbox visual basic.
Prior to opening the dialog box, my program checks to see if the player attacked has a dodge or block card in their hand (in the array), if that is true the dialog box opens.

After the dialogue box is open it reassigns my modular Player Turn Variable "T" to the value of the player attacking, changing it to that players turn.

Then I load my general sub

From there I load all of the attacked player's cards into checkboxes.

**Problem starts here**
After the cards are loaded I look at my summary index, at the players card index. The player keeps his card like he is suppose to, but somehow the index also randomly subtracts a card and adds a random card as well.

For example

The correct cards:

> Dodge 1
>
> Block 1
>
> HeadButt 1
>
> Slap 1
>
> Kick 1

'extras

> Poke -1
>
> Hail Mary 1

The code comparing cards:

```
If LunchMoneyMainForm.T = 0 Then
    For roll = 0 To 4
        Dim temp As IEnumerable(Of LunchMoneyMainForm.Group) = _
            From r In LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup _
            Where r.QuantityInteger > 0 _
            Select r
        If temp IsNot Nothing AndAlso temp.Count > 0 Then
            Dim rolls As Integer = roll Mod 5
            Number = (temp(LunchMoneyMainForm.Rnd.Next(0, temp.Count)).ID)
            LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger -= 1
            CheckBoxArray(rolls).Text = LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).CardNameString
            LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(roll) = Number
        End If
    Next roll
    For roll = 0 To 4
        Number = LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(roll)
        LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger += 1
    Next
End If
```

Is there a better way to do this?

EDIT: I commented out the

```
'For roll = 0 To 4
'    Number = LunchMoneyMainForm.NumberArray(roll)
'    LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger += 1
'Next
```

I also took out the `LunchMoneyMainForm.Player1HandGroup(Number).QuantityInteger -= 1`, but
I still get a +1 of an item and -1 of an item.

So something in my Linq function is doing it.

Edit:
My summary function for player cards.

```
Private Sub PlayerHandToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PlayerHandToolStripMenuItem.Click
        For Me.intCount = 0 To 27

            CountHandCards += Player1HandGroup(intCount).QuantityInteger + Player1HandGroup(intCount).QuantityInteger2 + Player1HandGroup(intCount).QuantityInteger3 _
                + Player1HandGroup(intCount).QuantityInteger4 + Player1HandGroup(intCount).QuantityInteger5

            HandMsg = HandMsg & Player1HandGroup(intCount).CardNameString & ": " & Player1HandGroup(intCount).QuantityInteger & "            " & Player1HandGroup(intCount).QuantityInteger2 & _
              "            " & Player1HandGroup(intCount).QuantityInteger3 & "            " & Player1HandGroup(intCount).QuantityInteger4 & "            " & Player1HandGroup(intCount).QuantityInteger5 & Environment.NewLine
        Next intCount

        MessageBox.Show("Card Quantities in Hand:" & Environment.NewLine & HandMsg & Environment.NewLine & "Hand Total: " & CountHandCards.ToString)
        HandMsg = ""
        CountHandCards = 0
    End Sub
```

I know the summary procedure works fine as it should, because the wrong data doesn't show up until I load the DodgeBlockCard dialog.

Comment: Its hard to judge from the limited code you posted, but do you clear `CheckBoxArray` before you call the code you posted?

Comment: No because it is being loaded in 5 checkboxes. That part works like it is suppose to. It is the quantityinteger amount that is getting the wrong numbers.

Comment: can you post the code that prints the result in your example?

Comment: I sat back and thought deeply for awhile, executed my program again, and realized that the card with the negative number was always the card the atker played, and the new card was always what the atkers new card should have been. What was happening is that the rest of myprogram was executing, and since I changed the turn temporary to the defending player so they can place a dodge or block card, the variables that minus and add a card to the attackers inventory would instead operate in the defenders inventory.

Comment: How can I halt my application until the dialog is closed?

Comment: From where is the dialog box shown vs the logic for continuing the game? If the dialog box is shown from within the method doing the game logic, it may be as simple as using [`ShowDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) in place of [`Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.show.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

To answer the "How can I halt my application until the dialog is closed?" question:

```
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
...
'Sleep for 1000 milliseconds
Sleep 1000
```

Comment: Will this just cause the application to halt for a set period of time? PS would some sort of DO Loop work as well?

Comment: it will halt the execution without clogging CPU with a Loop

Comment: Instead I finished the play button procedure and it fixed it that way.